# ¿Ayuda con la sincronizacion de hilos?

Tags: java, hilos

Buen día soy nuevo en esto de los hilos y me esta costando trabajo entenderlos estoy realizando un programa donde escribo un nombre con 3 hilos distintos para que los muestre de la siguiente manera 10 veces

> 1.- Alan Raul
>
> 2.- Alan Raul
>
> 3.- Alan Raul
>
> ....

El hilo1 se encarga de escribir el numero , el hilo2 escribe el nombre de Alan y el hilo 3 escribe el nombre de Raul el problema es que debo crear 2 hilos de hilo2 y 4 hilos de hilo3 y pues que estén sincronizados para los que los hilos de hilo2 escriban Alan y que los 4 hilos de hilo3 escriban Raul pero sin duplicar datos tengo código pero no esta funcionado correctamente me muestra los resultados de manera incorrecta:

> 1.- Raul Raul Raul Raul Alan Alan Raul Raul Raul
>
> 2.- Raul Alan Alan Raul Raul

estoy usando synchronized aunque no se si exista otra alternativa dejo el código que tengo al momento:

```
public class Tipo1 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i=1 ;i <=10; i++){
            System.out.print(i+".- ");
            try{
            Tipo1.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Error en la clase tipo1"+e);
            }
        }
    }   
}

public class Tipo2 extends Thread {
    public synchronized void EscribirNombre() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            try {
                Tipo2.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en la clase tipo2" + e);
            }  
            System.out.print("Alan ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EscribirNombre();
    }
}
public class Tipo3 extends Thread {

    public synchronized void EscSegundoNombre() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Raul ");
            try {
                Tipo3.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en la clase tipo4" + e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EscSegundoNombre();
    }
}
public class Prueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tipo1 tipo1 = new Tipo1();
        Tipo2 tipo2 = new Tipo2();
        Tipo2 btipo2 = new Tipo2();
        Tipo3 tipo3 = new Tipo3();
        Tipo3 btipo3 = new Tipo3();
        Tipo3 ctipo3 = new Tipo3();
        Tipo3 dtipo3 = new Tipo3();

        tipo1.start();
        tipo2.start();      
        btipo2.start();
        tipo3.start();
        btipo3.start();
        ctipo3.start();
        dtipo3.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: No necesitas usar `synchronized ` para este problema, simplemente crea el bucle en el `main` y adentro de el, invoca al método `start` de la clase `Tipo1`, luego, `Tipo1`, invocará a `Tipo2` y luego, `Tipo2`, invocará a `Tipo3`, a esto se lo denomina: *ejecutar un hilo, adentro de otro hilo* y listo, con esto solucionas el problema. Si es que quisieras usar `synchronized`, el inconveniente es que no sabes en que orden se ejecutará los hilos, entonces toca usar `var flags`. Pero como te dije anteriormente, ejecuta un hilo dentro de otro, ahí notaras la sincronización.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero como seria el bucle no entiendo muy bien esa parte

Comment: En vez de crear los bucles en cada método `run`, simplemente escribes **únicamente un bucle en el método `main`** y adentro de el, es donde invocas al hilo `Tipo1`. Luego en el método `run` del hilo 1, invocas al hilo 2 y luego en el `run` del hilo 2, invocas al hilo 3 y listo..

Answer (score 0):

Vas muy perdido, no te voy a dar la solución definitiva pero te aclaro el problema que tienes.

```
public synchronized void EscribirNombre() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        try {
            Tipo2.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en la clase tipo2" + e);
        }  
        System.out.print("Alan ");
    }
}
```

*synchronized* usa siempre un objeto que usa como semáforo. Un *thread* solo entrará en una región sincronizada si el semáforo está libre, y al entrar bloqueará el semáforo hasta que salga.

Al hacer un método de instancia *synchronized*, lo que haces es que usa la instancia como semáforo. Es decir, tu código es equivalente a

```
public void EscribirNombre() {
   synchronized (this) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Como cada thread se sincroniza consigo misma, todas las threads pueden entrar en su región sincronizada, no se estorban mutuamente y es como si no hubiera *synchronized*.

Puedes ver la diferencia si cambias todos tus métodos de esta forma:

```
public void EscribirNombre() {
   synchronized ("HOLA") { // Mismo String. Todos literales de String con el mismo texto son
                           // la misma instancia, aquí tus threads comparten semáforo.
      ...
   }
}
```

Verás que un método se ejecuta primero, hasta acabar del todo, luego otro, luego otro... Aquí si las distintas ejecuciones están sincronizadas.

A partir de aquí te queda, una vez te familiarices con los conceptos:

- definir mejor las regiones críticas (sincronizadas), de forma que solo abarquen lo necesario.
- no puedes controlar el orden en que se ejecutan los *threads* o en que estos acceden a la región crítica. Si tienen que coordinarse, tendrán que comunicarse; por ejemplo, mediante una variable de estado a la que todos accedan. En este caso, al salir del *sleep* y entrar en la región crítica, antes de imprimir un *thread* comprobaría si está en el estado que indica que le toca a él imprimir; si lo está, imprime y actualiza el estado, si no lo está, no hace nada, sale de la región crítica y vuelve a hacer un *sleep*.

Comment: Que tal gracias por la ayuda pero donde pones synchronized ("HOLA") en si el "HOLA" que significa ? o que se supone que se debe de colocar como argumento

Comment: "HOLA" es "HOLA". En este caso sirve como una instancia/objeto común para todos los thread, que demuestra lo que pasa cuando los thread compiten por un mismo semáforo (solo uno entra en la región crítica). También puedes usar cualquier instancia que sea común (por ejemplo que se la pases a los threads en los constructores). Por supuesto el texto del literal es lo de menos, mientras sea igual en todos los threads.

Comment: Pero como es que se la paso a los constructores

Comment: Pues con un constructor, con un método... como veas, dejando aparte que se puede ejecutar, un thread es un objeto como cualquier otro y le puedes definir métodos y constructores.

Comment: Una disculpa por poner de nuevo la pregunta pero ninguna de estas respuesta me ayudo así que decidí reestructurar con una mejor redacción mi pregunta para ver si recibía nuevas respuestas