# ¿Como sincronizar hilos?

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo que hacer un programa con tres hilos los cuales escriben un nombre para que los muestre de la siguiente manera 10 veces:

1.- Oscar Uriel

2.- Oscar Uriel

3.- Oscar Uriel

estoy realizando tres clases llamadas Tipo1, Tipo2, Tipo3 las cuales heredan de Thread, La clase de Tipo1 que es el hilo 1 se encarga de escribir el numero , la clase Tipo2 que es el hilo 2 se encarga de escribir Oscar y la clase Tipo3 que es el hilo 3 escribe Uriel, El problema es que mi profesor me pide que en el main instancie 2 hilos de la clase Tipo2 y 3 hilos de la clase Tipo3 y que los inicie  pero al momento de ejecutar el programa como tengo dos Hilos de tipo2 y 3 hilos de Tipo3 me escribe dos veces Oscar y tres veces Uriel de la siguiente manera:

1.-  Oscar Oscar Uriel Uriel Uriel

2.- Osca Oscar Uriel Uriel Uriel

.....

El profesor me dijo que tenia que sincronizar los hilos de la clase Tipo2 y Tipo3 pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo yo ya habia sincronizado los hilos y con un hilo de cada clase Tipo funcionaba correctamente pero al momento de agregar los hilos extra de Tipo2 y Tipo3 dejo de funcionar como lo soluciono por favor necesito su ayuda.Dejo el código que tengo al momento:

```
package clases;

public class Tipo1 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + ".- ");
            try {
                Tipo1.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en la clase tipo1" + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
package clases;

public class Tipo2 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Oscar ");
            try {
                Tipo2.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en la clase tipo2" + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
package clases;

public class Tipo3 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Uriel ");
            try {
                Tipo3.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en la clase tipo4" + e);
            }
        }
    }
}

package clases;

public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tipo1 tipo1 = new Tipo1();
        Tipo2 tipo2 = new Tipo2();
        Tipo2 btipo2 = new Tipo2();
        Tipo3 tipo3 = new Tipo3();
        Tipo3 btipo3 = new Tipo3();
        Tipo3 ctipo3 = new Tipo3();


        tipo1.start();
        try {
            tipo1.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el hilo 1" + e);
        }
        tipo2.start();
        try {
            tipo2.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el hilo 1" + e);
        }
        btipo2.start();
        try {
            btipo2.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el hilo 1" + e);
        }
        tipo3.start();
        try {
            tipo3.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el hilo 1" + e);
        }

        btipo3.start();
         try {
            btipo3.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el hilo 1" + e);
        }
        ctipo3.start();
         try {
            ctipo3.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el hilo 1" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355014/ayuda-con-la-sincronizacion-de-hilos/355039

Answer (score 0):

probaste con `synchronized`?
Te dejo este [enlace](https://javadesdecero.es/avanzado/sincronizacion-de-hilos/) donde lo explica mejor, a mi me ayudo tambien porque mi profesora tampoco explicaba

Comment: Si de hecho coloque synchronized en cada clase Tipo pero no funciono

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta.. Por favor mira [answer]